# Come to think of it vs Now that I think about it

Tags: idioms, comparison

Are 'now that I think about it' and 'come to think of it' used in the same way. 
According to a dictionary:

1) *Come to think of it* is used for adding something that you have just remembered about a subject that you are talking about. For example- 'I love getting her letters. Come to think of it, I haven’t had one for a while.'

2) *Now that I think about* it is used when you want to change your mind. For example- 'I used to think that a dry fall was a good thing, but now that I think about it, some rain is better than nothing.'

But in real life do people use them interchangeably or is it really used as mentioned above?

Comment: Some people "in real life" might use them interchangeably but their definitions are as you say.

Comment: If I say 'I love getting her letters. Now that I think about it, I haven’t had one for a while' it doesn't really make sense given that 'now that I think about it' is used when you want to change your mind. I'm not changing my mind here.

Comment: Then why don't you continue to phrase it the way you did in the question?

Comment: So they aren't interchangeable?